# Why can I use snake_case to call a CamelCase prototype function?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Looking at the documentation for [ripple-lib](https://github.com/ripple/ripple-lib/blob/develop/docs/REFERENCE.md), it indicates that you can call a function request_server_info on a Remote object. However, I couldn't find that function in the source code for Remote. It turns out that it's [prototyped as Remote.prototype.requestServerInfo](https://github.com/ripple/ripple-lib/blob/a651b6154d3b0549188812120643394d5c120d89/src/js/ripple/remote.js). Why can I call the function in snake_case rather than in camelCase? Where does this translation occur?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ripple code has a conversion process which maps camel case names to snake case.  It is done in the following function

```
// camelCase to under_scored API conversion
function attachUnderscored(c) {
```

This is why you can't find the snake case names in the code base, they don't actually exist.  It's all converted

Answer (score 0):

> Looking at the documentation for ripple-lib, why can I call the function in snake_case rather than in camelCase?

You cannot. The docs are simply outdated, there was [an API refactoring](https://github.com/ripple/ripple-lib/commit/08911ec2eed470125172b076a901e4191e199158) in November 2013.

Comment: The link returns 404. =(

Comment: @lid: Whoops, thank you. I cannot hold shift when typing closing parenthesis :-/